# Wrong 'Local Path' in DCOM Config entry

Tags: dcom

I have a component in DCOM Config whose 'Local Path' (on the General tab of the Properties page for that component in dcomcnfg) is pointing to the wrong place. However when I go to that directory and unregister the component using "componentname.exe /unregserver", the Local Path for that component remains unchanged.

I've also tried going to the correct directory and registering the component there, using "componentname.exe /regserver", but the value in 'Local Path' still doesn't change.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like that componentname.exe is not using the ProgID/GUID that you think it's using.  Either that or its register/unregister commands aren't working.  Do you have the source?  You could step through the registration routine and see what it's doing.